# QLibrary::load fails, but LD_LIBRARY_PATH just updated correctly before that, why?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, dynamic-loading, qlibrary

I have a library (let's call it mydll.so) that is dependent to an external application, i.e. Matlab. To dynamically load `mydll.so`, I have written a code like this (Ubuntu, g++ 4.8.5, qt 5.12.6):

```
// update LD_LIBRARY_PATH with ALL required paths (Matlab, boost, etc.)
bool res = qputenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", required_path.toStdString().c_str());
assert(res);

// loading the dll
QLibrary my_dll;

my_dll.setFileName(dll_path);
if (!my_dll.load())
{
   std::cout << my_dll.errorString().toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

The above code fails with this message:

```
Cannot load library /home/user/code/test/lnx_x64/debug/mydll.so: (libMatlabDataArray.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

It is strange because the `load()` function is complaining about a library from Matlab, i.e. `libMatlabDataArray.so` that its path is already included in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. But, if I run `ldd` on the same environment, I have:

```
user@everest:~/code$ ldd /home/user/code/test/lnx_x64/debug/mydll.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcb4da2000)
    libMatlabDataArray.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/extern/bin/glnxa64/libMatlabDataArray.so (0x00007f6af95f2000)
    libMatlabEngine.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/extern/bin/glnxa64/libMatlabEngine.so (0x00007f6af93e7000)
```

That means the `libMatlabDataArray.so` can be found by `ldd` command and the contents of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is correct. Then what can be the reason behind this issue in my case?

**Update 1:** If I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH before the application is started, everything works fine. What is the difference between setting the the LD_LIBRAARY_PATH before launching the application and inside it?

Comment: What `qputenv()` returns? Besides, are you sure your process used the newly set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` value? What if you set it *before* starting the application?

Comment: Run your binary with `strace -o log -f /path/to/my/binary`  Then `log` will show you where the library loader looked for your library.

Comment: @vahancho it returns true. Moreover, after calling `qputenv()` I added a line like `std::system("gnome-terminal");`. From the opened terminal, I saw that the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is OK and `ldd` works fine on that terminal too.

Comment: @vahancho If I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH before the application, it works fine!!! What can be the issue in this case?

Comment: @Gupta, when you modify the environment variable from a process, the process still used the old value. You should change the environment before starting the process.

Comment: @vahancho You are right. It was exactly my problem. If you want, you may put this point as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you change the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from within the process. However the process still uses the "old" environment variables block with old values. As a result it cannot properly find the dependent libraries and eventually fails.
Therefore your approach will not work. I would propose the following solutions:

- Set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable **before** starting the process, so that the process can take the updated block into account,
- Try to use `QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths()` function to set the library search paths.

Comment: If I use `QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths()` at run-time, can I load my libs afterwards?

Comment: I think so. Docs say about the function: `"Sets the list of directories to search when loading libraries..."`

Comment: I did the test. It was not working. It did not even update LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux.